# Android:Have an issue with TableLayout in landscape mode

Tags: android, landscape, tablelayout

I have wrote the following xml code to arrange buttons in tabular format but it is not working with me when run in the emulator or in my phone device where buttons shown one after the other (in vertical) and the last button is not showing at all.

The code is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="15dip"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:paddingLeft="20dip"
android:paddingRight="20dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:text="@string/main_title"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:textSize="24.5sp"/>
<TableLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:stretchColumns="*">
<TableRow >
 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/continue_button"
    android:text="@string/continue_label" />
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/game_button"
    android:text="@string/new_game_label" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/about_button"
    android:text="@string/about_label" />
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/exit_button"
    android:text="@string/exit_label"       />
  </TableRow>
  </TableLayout> 
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

this the example for creating the table layout please verify yours with this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

        </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

try doing this and for  clarifications